# Select top 20 results from database with option to view more

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a SQL query which loads the first 20 picture results from a database, I would like to give users the option to view more than 20 if they want to, or even create a tab to see the next 20 pictures, I'm stumped on how to input this code I'm sure its straight forward but I'm in a brain fart mode and really need to get over this hurdle.

Answer (score 1):

Look into LImit and offset features in MYSQL
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Excerpt from above link:

The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using prepared statements).

With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
```

To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;
```

With one argument, the value specifies the number of rows to return from the beginning of the result set:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5;     # Retrieve first 5 rows
```

Comment: The default load of the page is limited to 20, I will need button that changes the SQL statement to limit it to the selected length on the button correct?